# Can you change the CMD of the node layer - Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

I'm new to docker so i'm not sure if theres a much simpler way to go about it but. I want to use the node docker layer as my base layer, only the CMD in the dockerfile is set to  `CMD ["npm", "start]` by default. Is there anyway to change this initial CMD?

Reason for change:
I have a specific start script to enable production mode and i would prfer to keep my setup the same.

```
FROM node:6.6.0

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ONBUILD ARG NODE_ENV
ONBUILD ENV NODE_ENV $NODE_ENV
ONBUILD COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
ONBUILD RUN npm install
ONBUILD COPY . /usr/src/app

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you can create a new image from the base and just specify a new CMD:

```
FROM <image-which-does-almost-exactly-what-i-want>
CMD ["my", "replacement", "command"]
```

When you build your image, you can run it directly without adding a new command at the end. When the base image changes, just rebuild yours and you'll get all the updates.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just type the command you want to run at the end of docker run.

```
docker run <yourimage> <yourcommand>
```